# Fail to loop with 2 layer while controller

Tags: jmeter

[image]

As showed above, I would like to apply a 2-layer while controller. Each of them would have a CSV Data Set Config to retrieve inputs.

Illustrate that

Outer While Controller: read file A

1

2

3

4

5

Inner While Controller: read file B

6

7

8

I would like to get the following result by calling HTTP Request in Inner While Controller

1*6, 1*7, 1*8 (result of the 1st call of outer while controller)

2*6, 2*7, 2*8 (result of the 2nd call of outer while controller)

...

5*6, 5*7, 5*8 (result of the 5th call of outer while controller)

=============================================

However, I can only get the first line of file A for inner while controller. The Jmeter stops at 2nd calling on outer while controller.

What can be done to make the 2-layer while controller working?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that your [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) setup looks like:

   [image]
2. Rename the outer [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) to `While Controller 1`. Your 2 While Controllers need to have different labels so you could distinguish their current iterations exposed via a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in form of `__jm__<Name of your element>__idx`
3. Use the following [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter/) as the outer While Controller condition:

   ```
   ${__groovy((vars.get('__jm__While Controller 1__idx') as int) < new File('fileA.csv').readLines().size(),)}
   ```
4. Rename the inner While Controller to `While Controller 2`
5. Use the following __groovy() function as the inner While Controller condition:

   ```
   ${__groovy((vars.get('__jm__While Controller 2__idx') as int) < new File('fileB.csv').readLines().size(),)}
   ```
6. That's it, now you should be getting the desired inner/outer loops combination:

   [image]